# Apache Virtual Host - xxx.241.214.xxx:80 has no VirtualHosts

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu

I'm trying to set up a virtual host on a new VPS using apache 2.x on a Ubuntu server.

When starting apache I get the error " xxx.241.214.xxx:80 has no VirtualHosts", and the url for the site still points to the default location which means my virtual host file isn't taking effect:

```
<VirtualHost xxx.241.214.xxx:80>
ServerName xxx.co.uk
ServerAlias www.xxx.co.uk
DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/xxx.co.uk/httpdocs/xxx.co.uk
</VirtualHost>
```

Please help, I'm no good at all this server config stuff.

Comment: If you were talking about a program to edit your Apache configuration file, or re-generate your Apache configuration file from a database.. this question would be programming related and on topic.

This is a system administration topic, as such tagged as not programming related and offtopic.

Answer (score 1):

I know its been a while since you posted your question but I thought id throw in my thoughts

We currently run a few internal sites here for different purposes, all of them listen of standard port 80 and apache is set up simply as follows

```
Listen 80

NameVirtualHost *:80

# Site 1 Comment

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName site1.intranet
  ServerAdmin administrator@whatever.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site1
</VirtualHost>

#  Site 2 Comment

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName site2.intranet
  ServerAdmin administrator@whatever.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site2
</VirtualHost>
```

Our DNS is set up to route `http://site1.intranet` etc to the IP of the apache server and the apache config does the rest.

Answer (score 0):

I always use

```
<VirtualHost *>
```

(and ISTR always having problems specifying the IP and port number, which I think is why I do it that way now).